# Simplifying VBA Code

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a fully working VBA macro that goes through inputed client ID's and returns the specified commission fee for that client.

The code 100% works, however I need to have it so that my boss is able to easily add new clients with their special commission %'s to the list, without having to go through the VBA code.

How can I make a simplified VBA macro or just type an Excel function to do exactly what my code below does, but make it versitile to the special klient table?

**The main Excel table looks like this:**
[image]

**The table with the special klients, commission fees, currency, markets, looks like this:**
[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub komisijas_calc_Click()

'Declare the variables
Dim klienta_nr As Long
Dim ISIN As String
Dim Cena As Double
Dim Skaits As Double
Dim Komisija As Double
Dim vk As String
Dim Summa As Double
Dim kSheet As Worksheet

Dim lngFirstRow As Long: lngFirstRow = 2
Dim lngLastRow  As Long
Dim lngCol      As Long: lngCol = 2
Dim lngCounter  As Long
Dim lngKom As Long: lngKom = 11




Set kSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("spec_klienti")


With Worksheets(1)
    lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, lngCol).End(xlUp).Row

    For lngCounter = lngFirstRow To lngLastRow

    klienta_nr = Range("B" & lngCounter).Value
    ISIN = Range("E" & lngCounter).Value
    Cena = Range("H" & lngCounter).Value
    Skaits = Range("I" & lngCounter).Value
    vk = Range("D" & lngCounter).Value
    Summa = Cena * Skaits


Select Case klienta_nr



    Case 111111
                '(Vācija, Francija, Nīderlandes, Itālija, Īrija) - 30 EUR MIN
                If klienta_nr = 111111 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "DE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "FR" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "NL" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IE") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.01
                    .Cells(lngCounter, lngKom) = Komisija
                        End If
                If klienta_nr = 111111 And Komisija <= 30 Then
                    .Cells(lngCounter, lngKom) = 30
                        End If


                If klienta_nr = 1111111 And (Left(ISIN, 2) <> "DE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "FR" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "NL" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "IT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "IE") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.003
                    If Komisija >= 40 Then
                        .Cells(lngCounter, lngKom) = 40
                            End If
                        End If


    Case 2222222
                '(Vācija, Francija, Nīderlandes, Itālija, Īrija) - 30 EUR MIN
                If klienta_nr = 222222 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "DE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "FR" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "NL" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IE") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.01
                    .Cells(lngCounter, lngKom) = Komisija
                        End If
                'Set 30 EUR Min
                If klienta_nr = 2222222 And Komisija <= 30 Then
                    .Cells(lngCounter, lngKom) = 30
                        End If

                If klienta_nr = 2 And (Left(ISIN, 2) <> "DE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "FR" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "NL" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "IT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "IE") Then
                    GoTo AllElseFails
                        End If


Case Else

AllElseFails:

              'IP2, 0.03% komisija, 40 EUR/USD Max
                If Right(vk, 1) = 1 Or Right(vk, 1) = 8 Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.003
                    .Cells(lngCounter, lngKom) = Komisija
                        End If
              'IP1, 0.1% komisija, 40 EUR/USD Max
                If Right(vk, 1) = 7 Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.01
                    .Cells(lngCounter, lngKom) = Komisija
                        End If
                'Komisija MAX is 40, so anything >=40 equals 40
                If Komisija >= 40 Then
                    .Cells(lngCounter, lngKom) = 40
                        End If
            'End If
     End Select
   Next lngCounter
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This would be better on https://codereview.stackexchange.com as the code works. You just want to improve it.

Comment: I don't know if I need to rework the project through VBA or if I could just do it through Excel functions.